# Transparency on a UITableView causes navigation animation to look bad

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, transparency, user-experience

I'm using a UITableView with a Navigation Controller and I have made the former partially transparent, which looks great.

The problem I am running into is that when I press a button, the transition animation (to change to another view) looks odd because the old view that is sliding behind the new one is visible for a time.

I have tried things like temporarily shutting off transparency (either suddenly, or gradually), and while it looks a little better, overall the experience still isn't great.

I guess it might be possible to do a custom animation, but this seems like a bad idea since it will likely look different than the built-in OS animation. Actually, even with a custom animation I am not sure how I would do it since I think I would run into the same issue.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make things look cleaner?

UPDATE: adding more detail based on questions asked in the comments

The UI is a pretty complex set of pieces but I'll try to describe the relevant parts here.

There is a UISplitViewController [A], and I have created a UIVisualEffectView (with UIBlurEffect) that is attached as a subview of A's parent. My menu consists of a UINavigationController [B], and a UITableViewController [C] that is the top level of the menu. [B] is added as a subview as the content view of the blur effect view.

Two other UITableViewControllers [D] and [E] are transitioned to when button [1] or [2] are pressed on [C].

There are a few other view controllers that are subviews of [A] (or [A]'s parent) that are showing through, blurred, but that is the design and there is no issue there.

The problem is for the transition animations from [C]->[D], [D]->[C] (via back button), [C]->[E], or [E]->[C], you can see the controller that is moving away behind the controller that is coming in. So if you do [C]->[D] (via pressing button [1] on [C]) then you will see [C] going behind [D] as it slides in, and [C] eventually disappears.

The actual showing of [D] or [E] is done via a line of code like this (inside the custom class of [C])

```
self.navigationController?.show(myVC, sender: self)
```

where navigationController is [B] and myVC is [D].

The transition back to [C] is done via popViewController().

Comment: We need a little clarity... your tableview is "partially transparent"? Is it a `UITableViewController`? Or a table view as a subview of a controller's view? What's behind it that's showing through? Are you *pushing* a new controller onto the navigation stack? Or are you *presenting* a new controller?

Comment: @DonMag I have added some more details to my question to answer your questions. Any suggestions you can provide would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Tough to really understand your view hierarchy / setup. Best bet is to put together a [mre] so we can see exactly what's happening and, hopefully, offer a solution.

Comment: I am not sure if the setup matters that much. Basically, if you assume there is an animation of switching out one controller for another such that one partially overlaps the other, and both of them have partial transparency, you will see the part of the leaving controller that is not desirable to see. Basically I need a way to change the animation (it is the default one iOS is providing now), or somehow tweak the transparency so that it doesn't look awkward.

Answer (score 1):

OK - trying to (minimally) emulate your setup description...

- View controller with an image view filling the entire view
- Navigation controller added as a child VC
- Two VCs for the nav controller...

  - both with transparent background
  - "Page 1" pushes to "Page 2"

So I assume you mean you have a current "push/pop" transition that looks like this with simulator `Debug -> Slow Animations` to exaggerate the effect (these are kinda "heavy" gifs, so open them in a new browser tab if the animation isn't running):

[image]

And your goal is something close or similar to this:

[image]

You will likely need to use a custom transition.

I was able to get those results using the code from this article unedited: [Simple, custom navigation transitions](https://ordinarycoding.com/articles/simple-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions/) -- note: this is not mine - just found it from quick searching.

Here's the code for the full example -- everything is done via code, no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed. Just assign a new view controller's custom class as `NavSubVC` :

```
class NavSubVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "navBKG") else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let a = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Could not load \"navBKG\" image", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(a, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let rvc = Page1VC()
        let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rvc)
        self.addChild(navC)
        guard let navView = navC.view else { return }
        view.addSubview(navView)
        navC.didMove(toParent: self)
        navView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            navView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            navView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            navView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            navView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
        ])

        // let's have a gray nav bar always showing
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        
        // let's add a border to the navigation controller view
        //  so we can see its frame (since the controllers have clear backgrounds)
        navView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        navView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        
        // un-comment this line to see the custom transition
        //navC.addCustomTransitioning()
    }
}

class PageBaseVC: UIViewController {
    
    var labels: [UILabel] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        for i in 1...6 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "\(i)"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.textColor = .white
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
            labels.append(v)
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            labels[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            labels[1].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            labels[2].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[2].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            labels[3].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[3].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            labels[4].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[4].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            labels[5].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labels[5].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}

class Page1VC: PageBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Page 1"
        
        labels.forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        }
        
        let b = UIButton()
        b.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        b.setTitle("Push to Page 2", for: [])
        b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(b)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            b.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
        ])
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doPush(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func doPush(_ sender: Any?) {
        let vc = Page2VC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
}

class Page2VC: PageBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Page 2"
        
        labels.forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        }
        
    }
    
}

// Custom Navigation Transition
//  from: https://ordinarycoding.com/articles/simple-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions/
final class TransitionAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    // 1
    let presenting: Bool
    
    // 2
    init(presenting: Bool) {
        self.presenting = presenting
    }
    
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        // 3
        return TimeInterval(UINavigationController.hideShowBarDuration)
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // 4
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else { return }
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else { return }
        
        // 5
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        
        // 6
        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        if presenting {
            container.addSubview(toView)
        } else {
            container.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
        }
        
        // 7
        let toViewFrame = toView.frame
        toView.frame = CGRect(x: presenting ? toView.frame.width : -toView.frame.width, y: toView.frame.origin.y, width: toView.frame.width, height: toView.frame.height)
        
        let animations = {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                toView.alpha = 1
                if self.presenting {
                    fromView.alpha = 0
                }
            }
            
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1) {
                toView.frame = toViewFrame
                fromView.frame = CGRect(x: self.presenting ? -fromView.frame.width : fromView.frame.width, y: fromView.frame.origin.y, width: fromView.frame.width, height: fromView.frame.height)
                if !self.presenting {
                    fromView.alpha = 0
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration,
                                delay: 0,
                                options: .calculationModeCubic,
                                animations: animations,
                                completion: { finished in
            // 8
            container.addSubview(toView)
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}

final class TransitionCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    // 1
    var interactionController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition?
    
    // 2
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch operation {
        case .push:
            return TransitionAnimator(presenting: true)
        case .pop:
            return TransitionAnimator(presenting: false)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    // 3
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactionController
    }
}
extension UINavigationController {
    // 1
    static private var coordinatorHelperKey = "UINavigationController.TransitionCoordinatorHelper"
    
    // 2
    var transitionCoordinatorHelper: TransitionCoordinator? {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UINavigationController.coordinatorHelperKey) as? TransitionCoordinator
    }
    
    func addCustomTransitioning() {
        // 3
        var object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UINavigationController.coordinatorHelperKey)
        
        guard object == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        object = TransitionCoordinator()
        let nonatomic = objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UINavigationController.coordinatorHelperKey, object, nonatomic)
        
        // 4
        delegate = object as? TransitionCoordinator
        
        
        // 5
        let edgeSwipeGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        edgeSwipeGestureRecognizer.edges = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(edgeSwipeGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    // 6
    @objc func handleSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureRecognizerView = gestureRecognizer.view else {
            transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController = nil
            return
        }
        
        let percent = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizerView).x / gestureRecognizerView.bounds.size.width
        
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
            popViewController(animated: true)
        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
            transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController?.update(percent)
        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            if percent > 0.5 && gestureRecognizer.state != .cancelled {
                transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController?.finish()
            } else {
                transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController?.cancel()
            }
            transitionCoordinatorHelper?.interactionController = nil
        }
    }
}
```